# Visual Studio extension to show which command has been just executed?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

Is there a Visual Studio 2010 / 11 extension that would somehow monitor all commands that the developer is executing, either via mouse or keyboard, and show them in some window?

For IntelliJ IDEA, there is a [plugin](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?webide&id=4455) that can show keyboard shortcuts for actions executed on manus and toolbars. I am looking for something slightly different but for Visual Studio I couldn't find anything even remotely similar.

Any tips?

Comment: Would be interesting if a window would show the short cut keys that go with that command as a training tool.